How do I keep an individual part of a rig completely still while the rest of the rig continues to move?
I want to animate a character punching, but I want the fist to stop at the impact while the rest of the body continues to move. Is there some sort of anchoring mechanic? How do I put that into the keyframes?
Please be warned, I am both very new to Blender and a certified idiot. If you want to get through to me, you'll have to give me a direct tutorial or explain it in baby language.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

The thing you need is called "Inverse Kinematics" – often shortened to IK.
There are A LOT of videos on that topic, e.g. this one: =link=
Now - when you know what you need - just watch related videos.

UPD:
You can enable/disable IK during the animation.
In Pose Mode in the [Bone Constraints] tab you can edit IK's Influence:


Influence is 0 – IK disabled
Influence is 1 – IK enabled

You can animate this value:

Uncheck Only Show Selected (to see keyframes related to Influence)



Switch to the first frame of your animation (Shift+←):
Since you want IK disabled at first – set Influence to 0 and while hovering mouse cursor over that 0 – press I (this will create a keyframe for 0 value)
Then go to the frame, where IK should be switched
Set Influence to 1 and while hovering mouse cursor over that 1 – press I (this will create a keyframe for 1 value)
Now to make the switching instant – select all keyframes related to Influence, then RightMouseClick > Interpolation Mode > Constant :



That's it.
By the way,  you can switch IK not only once, but as many times as you want *by changing IK Influence from 0 to 1 and back from 1 to 0.
